# Extending new instance of a class

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to understand the code below for Scala. You have class B, and A which has dependency to the class B. Finally class C which extends A. When extending the class A code below is newing the B. What is significant of doing this? In Java you can't do this.

```
  class B {}
  class A( b:B ) {}
  class C extends A( new B) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is `B`?

```
class B {}
```

This is just an empty class. In Java, you would write the same.

#### What is `A`?

```
class A(b: B) {}
```

This is a class with one field. The constructor of the class takes one argument. The constructor sets the field to the argument. In Java, you would write this as follows:

```
class A {
  B b
  A(B b) {
    this.b = b
  }
}
```

#### What is `C`?

```
class C extends A(new B) {}
```

This is a subclass of A that sets the field `b` to `new B`. In Java, you would write this as follows:

```
class C extends A {
  C() {
    super(new B())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class C extends A(new B) {}
```

means that `C` has a no-argument primary constructor and on construction it calls the base class constructor with a new `B` instance. It is equivalent to:

```
public class C extends A
{
    public C() {
        super(new B());
    }
}
```